# Timeout problem between 2 executions (In the Query Console) of Javascript function declared in a module

Tags: module, marklogic

I defined the following module in the *Modules* database under '/test/test.mjs':

```
// test.mjs
export function test(message){
    xdmp.log("Received: "+message);
    return "Received: "+message;
}
```

I have the following code in the query console and I run it from a test database:

```
'use strict';
declareUpdate(); // I do not need here in this test case but I need it for my real code
import { test } from '/test/test.mjs';
test("Hello");
```

- It is working fine the first time.
- If I run it again, I am getting:
  *[javascript] XDMP-MODNOTFOUND: result: evalScriptOrModule(q) -- Module /test/test.mjs not found"*
- If I am waiting between 5 or 6 minutes and I run it again, it is working.

=> So it seems that a timeout is set somewhere when I am using a module inside the Query console (between 2 executions). Could you please give me an hint about it?

Comment: There is a conflict in your statements.  You refer to /test_data_mining/test.mjs regarding the error and /test/test.mjs elsewhere in your post.  Please review your approach, module names, errors and update the post to match.

Answer (score 0):

We solved the problem. It seems that it was coming from the configuration of the app server that we defined. Since we played also with it. The root was not equal to "/" anymore. We set it to "/" and now we do not have timeout problem between 2 executions.